# How to get rid of annoying message window in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The image and the title say all. As you can see that window covers a good portion of my terminal, which I very much like to read instead of this useless message window.

[image: message window]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77924326/836330 for how to disable these notifications from specific extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an explicit setting for it, I've found out that switching to "Zen-Mode" will silent notifications. 
[image]

But besides that, it seems like some of notifications can be disabled on an "extension basis" (See for "Live share" below).
[image]

Maybe there is some setting for "CMake Tools" you are using, which will allow you to adjust its notification settings.